# on Nextjs, how to perform a fetch request from an an external public api?

Tags: next.js, fetch-api

The api is public. Access privallages are to any and everyone.
I've made the same fetch-calls using frameworks such as angular, but on Nextjs I keep running into **cors policy errors**.
Can someone please explain how I can get the fetch call to work, or provide an example.
I can't fetch from local host as well. There's clearly an error in my practice.

> *'Access to fetch at '...' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.'*

Code example, if helpful:

```
let fetched =
     await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5001/helloWorld'
     , {        method: 'GET',
     
   }).then((result)=> console.log('promise complete', result.status));
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to set `mode:'cors'`

```
const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors',
 headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }
});
```

Comment: Not the issue for me.